# Jenkins Tomcat deploy : Context is defined in server.xml and may not be undeployed

Tags: maven, tomcat, jenkins

I get the following error when deploying an application with Jenkins through Maven, even though the context is definitely NOT defined in /etc/tomcat8/server.xml (there is no other server.xml on the server). Usually, deploying after restarting Tomcat works, but this problem is getting really annoying as it occurs very often. What could be the reason?

Thanks!

```
Redeploying [/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/MYAPP Java Backend/workspace/MYAPP/target/MYAPP-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war]
  Undeploying [/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/MYAPP Java Backend/workspace/MYAPP/target/MYAPP-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war]
ERROR: Build step failed with exception
org.codehaus.cargo.container.ContainerException: Failed to undeploy [/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/MYAPP Java Backend/workspace/MYAPP/target/MYAPP-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war]
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.undeploy(AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.java:140)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.redeploy(AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.java:178)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.deploy(CargoContainerAdapter.java:73)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$1.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:116)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$1.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:103)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:990)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:968)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.redeploy(CargoContainerAdapter.java:103)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.DeployPublisher.perform(DeployPublisher.java:61)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$3.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:45)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:782)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:723)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.post2(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:1047)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:668)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1763)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:531)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:410)
Caused by: org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManagerException: FAIL - Context /MYAPP is defined in server.xml and may not be undeployed

    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.invoke(TomcatManager.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.invoke(TomcatManager.java:480)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.undeploy(TomcatManager.java:420)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.Tomcat7xRemoteDeployer.performUndeploy(Tomcat7xRemoteDeployer.java:62)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.undeploy(AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.java:130)
    ... 17 more
org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManagerException: FAIL - Context /MYAPP is defined in server.xml and may not be undeployed

    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.invoke(TomcatManager.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.invoke(TomcatManager.java:480)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.undeploy(TomcatManager.java:420)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.Tomcat7xRemoteDeployer.performUndeploy(Tomcat7xRemoteDeployer.java:62)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.undeploy(AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.java:130)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.redeploy(AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.java:178)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.deploy(CargoContainerAdapter.java:73)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$1.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:116)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$1.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:103)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:990)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:968)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.redeploy(CargoContainerAdapter.java:103)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.DeployPublisher.perform(DeployPublisher.java:61)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$3.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:45)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:782)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:723)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.post2(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:1047)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:668)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1763)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:531)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:410)
Build step 'Deploy war/ear to a container' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: Did you ever get to the bottom of this. Am experiencing something similar with tomcat manager text http calls.?

Comment: Have just encountered same error when using the manager API via salt. In our case it seems to have been because the deployment was taking a very long time, and (I suspect) also the undeployment, causing an overlap where it was trying to deploy something that was still deployed. Workaround was to increase salt's timeout for connecting to the manager.

Answer (score 0):

In my case this happens while the app is starting up.
Either stop in in the manager or wait for it to die due to some error on start-up

Answer (score -1):

In my case, those error messages occurred when I had added `<Context>` configuration in `server.xml`.

I had set `[Context docBase="MyApp" path="/" source="{MyApp.location}"]`  in server.xml.

Try to remove `<Context>` configuration in `server.xml`.

Comment: "even though the context is definitely NOT defined in /etc/tomcat8/server.xml"